# <url-pattern> in filter mapping is not valid

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, filter, mapping

I have a @POST rest method and i want to make filter for it, so only the person who is logged in in the application to be able to have access to it. 
Here is my @POST method :

```
@POST
@Path("/buy")
public Response buyTicket(@QueryParam("projectionId") String projectionId, @QueryParam("place") String place){
    Projection projection = projectionDAO.findById(Long.parseLong(projectionId));
    if(projection != null){
        System.out.println(projection.getMovieTitle());
        System.out.println(place);
        projectionDAO.buyTicket(projection, userContext.getCurrentUser(), place);
    }

    return Response.noContent().build();
}
```

And here is the filter i write for this method :

```
@WebFilter("rest/projection/buy")
public class ProtectedBuyFunction implements Filter {
@Inject
UserContext userContext;

public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (!isHttpCall(request, response)) {
        return;
    }
    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    User currentUser = userContext.getCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser == null) {
        String loginUrl = httpServletRequest.getContextPath()
                + "/login.html";
        httpServletResponse.sendRedirect(loginUrl);
        return;
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}

private boolean isHttpCall(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) {
    return (request instanceof HttpServletRequest)
            && (response instanceof HttpServletResponse);
}

public void destroy() {
}}
```

The problem is that i always get an exception and the server refuse to start, the exception is :

```
Invalid <url-pattern> rest/projection/buy in filter mapping
```

I am using TomEE server with Jax-RS. Is there some way I can solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping path as per servlet specification should follow rules:

- **Directory Mapping:** A string beginning with a ‘/’ character and ending with a ‘/*’ suffix is used for path mapping.
- **Extension Mapping:** A string beginning with a ‘*.’ prefix is used as an extension mapping.
- **Context Root:** The empty string ("") is a special URL pattern that exactly maps to the
  application's context root, i.e., requests of the form http://host:port//. In this case the path info is ’/’ and the servlet path and context path is empty string (““).
- **Default Servlet:** A string containing only the ’/’ character indicates the "default" servlet of the application. In this case the servlet path is the request URI minus the context path and the path info is null.
- **Exact Mapping:** All other strings are used for exact matches only.

In your case, it does not start with "/". You should have absolute url for context root if you are using servlet filter. Add "/" in the beginning. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is to use JAX-RS filters and not Servlet Filters. you can find here a documentation of them: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9580

In case of your Servlet Filter, please post your servlet context and what is the mapping for JAX-RS resources, in order to figure out why you get the error.