# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> WelcomeServlet in servlet mapping

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets, illegalargumentexception, url-pattern

I have installed tomcat server to work with my dynamic web project on eclipse Luna. The server seems to be running fine when I dont load it with any project file but when I load my project it gives the error "Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start." I have checked my project and there seems to be no error in it. These are the server startup messages that I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> WelcomeServlet in servlet mapping
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3325)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3300)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.configureContext(WebXml.java:1438)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1357)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:889)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5419)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: show the code of your `WelcomeServlet`: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> WelcomeServlet in servlet mapping`

Comment: Also add your web.xml servlet configuration if you are not using annotations.

Answer (score 0):

You used incorrect syntax for the url pattern of the WelcomeServlet. Make it `<url-pattern>/WelcomeServlet</url-pattern>`. I added a `/` before the name of the Servlet.

Comment: Thanks alot, I had missed / in <url-pattern>. Now its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Servlet mapping can be defined two ways:

- `<servlet-name>` for Named Servlets
- `<url-pattern>` for url patterns.

**Using servlet-name**

> ```
> <servlet-mapping>
>     <servlet-name>WelcomeServlet</servlet-name>
> </servlet-mapping>
> ```

OR

**Using url-pattern**

> ```
> <servlet-mapping>
>     <url-pattern>/WelcomeServlet</url-pattern>
> </servlet-mapping>
> ```

If you are interested in knowing the rules for **url-pattern**, Refere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31089735/url-pattern-in-filter-mapping-is-not-valid/31094118#31094118)